# не похоже было, что(бы) ему кто-то поверил

Tags: союзы

Подскажите, будьте добры: Не похоже было, что(бы) ему кто-то поверил.
(он солгал, и ему никто не поверил)

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то  заключается? Если вы спрашиваете, нужно ли "бы", то можно и так, и так. Но с "бы" звучит лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Не похоже было, что ему кто-то поверил = Было похоже, что ему никто не поверил.

Не похоже было, чтобы ему кто-то поверил = Было похоже, что ему никто не поверил **и не поверит**.

Не похоже было, что ему бы кто-то поверил = Было похоже, что ему никто не  поверит.

*Чтобы* обычно употребляется с глаголом прошедшего времени. Но в значении будущего или настоящего перфекта. Здесь имеем тот самый случай, порождающий различия в высказываниях.

Аналогично во фразе:

> И это заставляет задуматься о наших телевизионных мыслителях, у
> которых многомиллионная аудитория, и вроде не похоже, чтобы они
> отпихивали какой-то помёт, а вот мыслей нет как нет.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что без "бы" звучит лучше. "Не похоже было, что кто-то поверил". Хотя формально запретить вариант с "чтобы" я не могу, грамматически он не ошибочен. Видимо, это сугубо авторское чувство стиля, на которое нет формальных правил.

Но, с другой стороны, что есть исходная фраза? Это всего лишь прямое отрицание высказывания "похоже было, что ему кто-то поверил". И вот в этом, прямом, высказывании, "бы" совершенно невозможно. Так зачем оно в отрицании?

*Признаюсь, я попытался подвести под свой ответ более фундаментальную базу, разобравшись с грамматическими функциями этого "чтобы" (это ведь своего рода модальные наклонения "условное возможное", "условное невозможное", возможное нереализованное" и т. д. - можете посмотреть при желании в корпусной грамматике). Но попытка эта завела меня в такие академические дебри, что я оставил эту идею, убоявшись запутать себя и вас. Поэтому авторитетность ответа - на уровне моего частного мнения.*

Answer (score -2):

Очень интересный вопрос.

Оба варианта кардинально меняют смысл.

`Не похоже было, что ему кто-то поверил` полностью соответствует `ему никто не поверил`. Это ответ на вопрос.

Значение второго варианта совершенно меняет смысл. При употреблении `чтобы` всегда можно добавить `того / с тем / для того`, что разъяснит смысл этого варианта (первые 2 не подходят по согласованию):
Это было не похоже, (для того) чтобы ему поверить (кто-то поверил). Этот вариант очень несамостоятельный и его не понять без предыдущего контекста. Пример интерпретации смысла: художник неудачно скопировал картину, и ему никто не поверил, что это оригинал. То есть что-либо было не похоже на оригинал.

Употребление `чтобы` в значении первого варианта не корректно. Но люди смысл поймут.

Comment: "Я хочу чтобы он ушел" -- И как вы тут вставите "для того" ?