# Прошу помочь. Пунктуация

Tags: запятые

Сломала себе голову, размышляя, нужна ли запятая в этом предложении. С одной стороны, вроде, оно сложносочиненное. Но интуиция говорит, что запятая не нужна. Прошу помочь.

"Под таблицами нет подписи, и не указано название организации/отдела, их составившего".

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно говорит интуиция, это сложносочиненное предложение, но "Под таблицами" - общая часть обоих предложений, поэтому и нет запятой.

***Под таблицами*** нет подписи и (под таблицами) не указано название организации/отдела, их составившего.

Answer (score 1):

*Под таблицами* - общий элемент для двух простых предложений. Тогда запятую ставить не нужно.

Но как же узнать наверняка, общий ли это элемент по смыслу?
В случаях, если простые предложения можно **поменять местами**, запятая точно не ставится:
*Под таблицами не указано название организации/отдела и нет подписи.* || Если такой вариант тоже подходит, то запятая не нужна.

Если название организации не указано в общем, а не именно под таблицами, то запятая нужна. Тогда "под таблицами" относится только к подписи. То есть теоретически возможны два варианта: с запятой и без.

Comment: Да, такое вполне возможно.

Comment: Мне просто нравится просчитывать все теоретически возможные варианты, даже [самые нелепые](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454108/не-похоже-было-чтобы-ему-кто-то-поверил/) - особый случай.